# How to display custom twitter posts with the twitter plugin?

Tags: twitter

Using the twitter plugin, so you can have your twitter posts loaded into the sidebar of your wordpress blog, is there any way of filtering the posts?

For example, I will post technical stuff I'm interested in on twitter, I want that to show up on my blog, but I may also post non-related items, how can I filter these out so they dont show on the blog?

Simple answer would be to have two separate twitter accounts, but then I'd lose followers etc

Comment: **Which** Twitter plug-in are you using?  There are several ... but generally speaking, they all just fetch a stream of data from the Twitter API, so there's no way to filter posts without doing so manually ...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the particular Twitter plugin you're using, you could filter based on the presence of a particular hash tag. [Twitter Tracker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-tracker/) appears to have the ability to do this when the search is of the form `#hashtag from:username`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Tweet Blender](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tweet-blender/) plugin. I recently added this to our site to allow only certain contributors with using a predefined hash tag to have their posts show up. This helped prevent twitter users using the same hash tag from showing up, and gave the contributors the freedom to post "random" items to their own feed.

Answer (score 0):

In the reality of it, its impossible to filter tweets from an account without the use of handles. All this plugins will have to work via the use of hashtags which it seems you cant provide. But you can filter tweets according to keywords too though.